# Put numbers from Fraction() object into a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of:

```
[Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(2, 5), Fraction(5, 7), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(1, 5), Fraction(3, 7), Fraction(2, 9), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(2, 7), Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(2, 9), Fraction(4, 9)]
```

And I need to put the Fraction() numbers in a list of tuples:

```
[(1,3),(2,5),... and so on]
```

I tried this:

```
def frtuples(fractionList):
    listt = []
    for item in fractionList:
        num = item.numerator
        den = item.denominator
    tuplee = (num, den)
    return tuplee
```

But all I get is:

```
(4,9)
```

To be honest I dunno how to get rid of the Fraction()

Comment: You're only returning the last tuple, and never using the listt...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are only saving last iteration value to `tuple` and returning it, You need to add those `tuples` to `list` and return `list`

```
def frtuples(fractionList):
  listt = []
  for item in fractionList:
     num = item.numerator
     den = item.denominator
     tuplee = (num, den)
     listt.append(tuplee)
  return listt
```

Or you can use list comprehension

```
def frtuples(fractionList):
     return [(item.numerator,item.denominator) for item in fractionList]
```

Comment: Basically what I did was after 'tuplee = (num, den)' I added another line: 'new = listt.append(tuplee)' and then 'return new'. This gave me 'None' and it didn't work at all. Thats why I thought my whole code was wrong. So I believe I should not have put it into a new variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def frtuples(fractionList):
    listt = []
    for item in fractionList:
        num = item.numerator
        den = item.denominator
        tuplee = (num, den)
        listt.append(tuplee)
    return listt
```

You need to append the tuple in the list defined above the for loop and then return the list in stead of the tuple.

**Output**

```
>>> l = [Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(2, 5), Fraction(5, 7), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(1, 5), Fraction(3, 7), Fraction(2, 9), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(2, 7), Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(2, 9), Fraction(4, 9)]
>>> frtuples(l)
[(1, 3), (2, 5), (5, 7), (1, 3), (1, 6), (1, 4), (1, 5), (3, 7), (2, 9), (1, 3), (2, 7), (5, 8), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 9), (4, 9)]
```